# Font Installation (what do I have --- Ubuntu?)

Tags: fonts

I have a feeling that I'll be directed to a previous answer, but here goes.

I have purchased a copy of Linotype's Optima font (no TeX package) from linoletter@linotype.com. They give instructions for MAC and Windows installation but not for Linux (I use Ubuntu).
I have managed to put the font files as directory `Optima` in `home/Linotype/Purchased_fonts/Linotype/Fonts`. (I have several other Linotype fonts in that directory as well). The particular new fonts are called `OptimaLTSd.otf` etc.

I have submitted several fonts to TeXlive in the past but my memory is not what it was [GOM].

1) I have vague memories that there is a Linux command that lists all the available fonts. What is it and how should I make known my new font(s)?

2) How should I make known to `pdfLaTeX` (or perhaps better another `...LaTeX`) that I want to use my new font?

Comment: `fc-list` should list the fonts available to your operating system, If the font shows up there it should be immediately usable by lualatex and xelatex, making it available for pdftex is more involved (especially if you want to make several different 256-character subsets available)

Comment: For installation of the fonts look here: https://askubuntu.com/a/18359/700522 (But it is not necessary.) For usage, use XeLaTeX with the command 
`\setmainfont[
Path = /home/Linotype/Purchased_fonts/Linotype/Fonts/,
(BoldFont = OptimaLTSd-Bold.otf),
(ItalicFont = OptimaLTSd-Italic.otf),
(BoldItalicFont  = OptimaLTSd-BoldItalic.otf)]
{OptimaLTSd(-Regular).otf}`. Every parenthesis content has to be ignored if no such file exist (no Bold support for example)

Comment: Suggestion: Use LuaLaTeX (backup plan, XeTeX) and load fonts via `fontspec` syntax. No font *.sty required. I have various fonts for which I purchased the font licenses; works great. I believe that on Linux, shell command `fc-cache` will update your system fonts, including those in home folder, as long as they are on a standard path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to every one who responded, all of whom provided useful information, including pointers to other help sites.

I think that my main problem was with Ubuntu's `su` command. I was trying to add the `opentype` directory into the `\usr\share\fonts` directory but `su` didn't help. In the end I did (as far as I can remember) in directory `\usr\share\fonts`:

```
> sudo -i
> gave my regular password
> mkdir opentype
> chmod 777 opentype % so I can add to the directory as non-root
> exit % to get out of root mode
```

Then I could add, as a regular user, my Linotype font directories into `/usr/share/fonts/opentype` and run

```
> fc-cache % take note of any new font
> fc-list  % list known system fonts
```

to get a list of the system fonts (including my new Linotype ones).

After that the fonts were available as system fonts for the LaTeX versions that could use them.

Apologies if this is too Linux (Ubuntu) specific.